# How to add swagger's codes in Markdown

Tags: swagger, markdown

I'm writing some documentation for the API and I need to add swagger code in my markdowm document. May I post this beautiful swagger's block into markdown file and save the structure of swagger?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "Swagger code"?

Comment: Could you please explain your use case in more details? Do you mean you want to insert a code block in the [operation description section](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39929108/113116) section (along with "Cоздание пустого документа")? Or something else?

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work about it?