# Inline image in description text of openapi3/swagger

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, openapi

Is it possible to render inline images as part of description texts etc in openapi3.0/swagger?
When looking at the spec, all I can find is the ability to link to images in request examples, specifically. What I want is to be able to include diagrams etc in introductory texts of my API, similar to markdown etc. Example:

```
openapi: 3.0.2
info:
  version: "1.0.0"
  title: "My API"
  description: "This API bla bla bla [block diagram] bla bla [another inline image]"
```

Is anything like this at all possible?

Comment: Related (or duplicate): [How to format OpenAPI/Swagger text descriptions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39924144/113116)

Answer (score 4):

At least with the ReDoc renderer, it seems possible to use HTML straight into your description texts, so adding `<img src="./image.png" />` appears to work:

```
openapi: 3.0.2
info:
  version: "1.0.0"
  title: "My API"
  description: "This API bla bla bla <img src="./block-diagram.png" /> bla bla <img src="./another-inline-image.png" />
```

I don't know if there's a better way or if there are limitations to this approach such as cross-origin issues.