# Multiline strings in swagger editor

Tags: yaml, swagger, swagger-ui

If I paste the following spec in editor.swagger.io:

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.0
info:
  title: Callback Example
  version: 1.0.0
paths:
  /streams:
    post:
      description: |
        first line
        second line
        third line
      responses:
        '201':
          description: subscription successfully created
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                description: subscription information
                required:
                  - subscriptionId
                properties:
                  subscriptionId:
                    description: this unique identifier allows management of the subscription
                    type: string
                    example: 2531329f-fb09-4ef7-887e-84e648214436
```

The description is rendered on a single line:

```
first line second line third line
```

Even though the yaml spec states that block style strings preserve newlines: https://yaml-multiline.info/

How do I use multiline strings in swagger editor?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I break a string over multiple lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3790454/113116), [How to format OpenAPI text descriptions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39924144/113116)

Answer (score 6):

You can use one of the below-mentioned solutions to get multiline in swagger.

**Solution 1:**

```
description: |
  first line \
  second line \
  third line
```

[image]

**Solution 2:**

```
description: |
  first line <br>
  second line <br>
  third line
```

[image]

Comment: Hint: Save a headache by making sure there is a space before the \ and no space after the \

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the *br* tag in the following way:

```
  description: |
    First line. <br> Second line.<br> Third line
```

Or this also works:

```
  description: First line. <br> Second line.<br> Third line
```