# Adding images to Swagger docs

Tags: python, swagger, openapi, fastapi

I am writing some Rest APIs using Python FastAPI. There is a requirement to add a lot of custom sections in the Swagger - OpenAPI docs. This includes fields for contact information for each API, author information, Image showing data model, database fields etc.

Is there any way to do all this using the [Fast API built-in OpenAPI capabilities](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/extending-openapi/#self-hosting-javascript-and-css-for-docs)?
I know that it is possible to host our own custom json file. But I do not know how to add an image to the swagger json file. Nor do I know how to add custom fields to the same.

Is there any template I can use to pretty much host a HTML version of the swagger docs?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: See [How to format OpenAPI descriptions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39929108/113116) - you can use Markdown formatting, including the `![alt text](https://path/to/image.png)` syntax for images.

Answer (score 3):

ReDoc uses standard HTML tags in its `description` tags.

```
description: |
  An example image
  <img alt="Example" src="../images/example.png" />
```